# Kubernetes VPA as recommender for resource specification estimation

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We decided to use VPA in our AKS cluster as a solution for estimating the App required resources for our developers, so that they can give the resource specification in accordance with the usage of the app and not with a random guess . We assume the values recommended by VPA is a trusted one and can be directly used as per its suggestion.

So here noticed that VPA is recommending very lower values in comparison with what we used, So would like to understand below points.

- What are the factors VPA will be considering when its providing a recommended values.
- The VPA recommended values are static or it will be different or dynamic with each point of time?
- In our case our spring boot applications are taking more resources during its startup, and the actual usage will be less.. So will VPA will consider the startup resource requirement also, else it may fail our applications with this lower recommendation.
- Can we generate or get a better view  (in a table format) for each apps and its VPa recommendation based on namespace? so that it can be automated using azuredevops pipeline and will generate or post the resulted tab to Azure Wiki dynamically.

Below is an sample recommendation provided by VPA.

```
Recommendation:
    Container Recommendations:
      Container Name:  MyContainer
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:     10m
        Memory:  978002549
      Target:
        Cpu:     11m
        Memory:  1038683533
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:     11m
        Memory:  1038683533
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:           12m
        Memory:        1180712687
      Container Name:  istio-proxy
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:     10m
        Memory:  93607494
      Target:
        Cpu:     11m
        Memory:  93633096
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:     11m
        Memory:  93633096
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:     12m
        Memory:  106436446
```